# InstallShield: error C8101: 'Name' : must specify DLL for this function

Tags: installshield

While building after upgrading from InstallShield 5.x to InstallShield 2016, I see the below errors & warnings:

```
error C8101: 'QueryServiceStatus' : must specify DLL for this function
error C8101: 'OpenSCManagerA' : must specify DLL for this function
error C8101: 'CloseServiceHandle' : must specify DLL for this function
error C8101: 'CreateServiceA' : must specify DLL for this function
error C8101: 'QueryServiceStatus' : must specify DLL for this function
```

Please let me know how to overcome them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check for the custom action named "QueryServiceStatus" in Installshield. The source folder for the dll might changed in upgrade process.

Comment: Don't buy it. Never buy InstallShield. Very dirty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the custom action named "QueryServiceStatus" in Installshield. The source folder for the dll might changed in upgrade process.